# How to execute an action after event="uploadcomplete" in RichFaces <a4j:ajax>

Tags: richfaces

I need to call the `checker()`method after a `fileUpload` `event="uploadcomplete"`.

```
public void checker()
{fileProcessingEJB.checkInventoryToResolveAll();}
```

The following code does the file upload and I need to execute something after all files have been uploaded. Do I do that after `<rich:fileUpload> </rich:fileUpload>` this? or I can call the method in `execute` attribute in `<a4j:ajax>` ?

```
<rich:fileUpload 
    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}"
    id="upload" acceptedTypes="xml"
    ontyperejected="alert('Only XML files are accepted');"
    maxFilesQuantity="50">
<a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="#@none" render="info" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this [Thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/10910)

You can use listener like below.

```
<rich:fileUpload id="generic_data_file" fileUploadListener="#{controller_bean.uploadFile}"
     <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" actionListener="#{controller_bean.loadInfoFileHook}"/>
</rich:fileUpload>
```

if you want to do any action you can do at `actionListener`.

**Or**

if you want to display a message, look at this [Issue thread](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-3566) (may depend on your version)

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use `actionListener`, since I am using RichFaces 4.2.2 Final, it is `<a4j:actionListener>`.